# How can I test Iphone compability without an Iphone?

Tags: iphone, web, media-queries, simulator

Hi is there any online simulators to test iphone compability that works with media queries.
I have tried to look for somthing to allow me to test my webpage on iphone and Ipad. But I havent found any tools as of yet is there such a tool? Thank you for your help.

I have tried resizeing the window but this dose not work for me in chrome im using chrome window resizer. What sizes should I set for media querys like this to kick in?

```
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
#header {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);      
}
}​
```

Comment: http://iphonetester.com/ Did not work well for me. nowadays iphone/android screen resolutions are bigger than what this tester emulates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these to test your designs
http://iphonetester.com/

http://www.responsinator.com/

http://protofluid.com/

http://quirktools.com/screenfly/

Answer (score 2):

There are tons of supposed iPhone emulators available online. A quick search of "iphone emulator" returned 30 million+ results.

If you simply want to test a web page you could run the site in Safari, with your window resized to the correct size. It won't be a perfect test, but would give you a good indication of what the website would look/behave like on an iPhone/iPad.

Comment: Okay so safari with the right dimensions should let me test this??

Comment: Also using Safari's Develop menu to change your user agent to an iPhone or iPad version of MobileSafari may help. However, there are some behaviors that won't be the same even if you're only testing simple rendering; e.g. form controls look different on iOS. If you have a Mac handy, get Xcode and use its iOS Simulator app.

Comment: How can i test it on windows? thanks for the comments I have tried setting this in chrome can it be done?